# Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google' NAND: could not write file /tmp/android-ehdg/emulator-xxjXQs, File exists

Tags: emulation, android-virtual-device

When I try to run an android emulator I get the error "NAND: Could not write file...file exists". When searching on this error on answer said I needed to free up some space on my hard drive. I have since freed up a few Gig from the hard drive but I still get the same error. 
I get this error whether I am running the avd manager form Eclipse or from the command line. Does anyone know Why I am getting the NAND: Could not write file...file exists error or why I always get the message about the emulator running.

Answer (score 1):

It's a real disturbing situation when error can't completely describe problem in detail!
finally I figured out all this kind of error messages ("File Exists" and "There is no space") are due to small amount of mounted space on /tmp folder.
in Linux try `mount` and you'll see specified parameters of tmpfs and /tmp

changing $ANDROID_TMP value is not a proper solution and even doesn't work at all.

try editing **fstab**

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

and increase /tmp size to a larger value that makes sense to you (like:1500M)
then **reboot** system

*PS: It's not IDE-dependent (Eclipse or Android-Studio) but something that deal with AVD Emulator*